# ios UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey not work with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        //You should handle the call back here.
        print(url)
        return true
    }
```

This method working but when i open firebase;

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

That method not work please help any idea ?

Same crash i think
[iOS app crashes when I write FirebaseApp.configure()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763870/ios-app-crashes-when-i-write-firebaseapp-configure)

Comment: Try This   FIRApp.configure()

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue and I'm not sure how I should handle it, but if you go to your info.plist and set `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to boolean `NO`, it starts working again.